# Sorting table header anchor shows blank page when if(isset($_post [ ‘submit’]))

Tags: php, database, sorting, submit, anchor

I have tables in a database that I want to sort by clicking on the table header. Everything works well except that when the tables are in the same PHP file, the anchor click shows a blank page.

If a table is on a file, The sorting works normal but I have have many tables in the same PHP file. How can I do it so that the many tables will still be in one PHP file and the sorting working normal.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
 $orderBy = "amount";
 $order = "asc";

 if(!empty($_GET["orderby"])) {
    $orderBy = $_GET["orderby"];}
  if(!empty($_GET["order"])) {
    $order = $_GET["order"];}

  $firstname = "asc"; $lastname = "asc"; $amount = "desc";

  if($orderBy == "firstname" and $order == "asc") {
    $firstname = "desc";}
  if($orderBy == "lastname" and $order == "asc") {
    $lastname = "desc";}
  if($orderBy == "amount" and $order == "desc"){
    $amount = "asc";}
  if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {  
        try { 
   echo "<table id='Table1' class='table table_bordered'>
   <thead><tr><th><a href='?orderby=firstname&order=$firstname'>First 
   Name</a></th><th><a href='?orderby=lastname&order=$lastname'>Last 
   Name</a></th><th><a href=?orderby=amount&order=$amount'>Amount</a> 
   </th></tr></thead>"; 
         
   $result = $pdo->query("SELECT firstname, lastname, amount 
   from table1 where (amount != 0) ORDER BY $orderBy $order");
     foreach ($result as $row) {    
      echo "<tbody><tr><td>{$row['firstname']}</td><td> 
  {$row['lastname']}</td><td>{$row['amount']}</td></tr></tbody>";}} }  

<form method="post" action="headerSorting.php">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit1">
</form>
```

Comment: Clicking a link means a GET request, so `isset($_POST['submit1'])` of course won’t be true in that situation.

Comment: Not to mention that your links don't contain a `submit1` parameter in their querystrings either.

Comment: P.S. Any reason you don't employ client-side sorting using Javascript? It would mean a lot less load on your server. There are lots of JS table plugins which can provide this automatically.

Comment: I have tried some including TableManager but they seem to be slow in handling large table. I prefer the Server side

Comment: If your table is that large you should be using pagination anyway, otherwise it will be unmanageable for any user to take in that amount of information, and unnecessary for the server to keep serving such large amounts of data when probably the user is not reading all of it.

Comment: Anyway it's unclear what the purpose of the form `<form method="post" action="headerSorting.php">
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit1">
</form>  ` is in your code, or why you wrapped all the display code in `if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) { ` (so that it would only show the table when that form has just been submitted).

Comment: Thanks ADyson for your concern and reply.

Actually the tables are many on one php file. That is the reason for the if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) { , if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {  etc so that they can be submitted independently. If I put one table code in a php file, the sorting works normal the way I want, but if I put more than one table in a php file, the sorting doesn't work. It shows a blank page. I want the many tables in a single php file and also be able to sort tables.

Comment: Then your links will need to include the submit1 parameter, and the code will need to check for that using GET, and the form will need to submit using GET as well. I thought this was explained in the earlier comments already, or at least we pointed you towards that conclusion

Comment: Please can you give example

Comment: Why, what bit of the description wasn't clear? E.g. `<a href='?submit1=Submit1&orderby=firstname&order=$firstname'>`, (and same for your other sorting links), and `<form method="get" action="headerSorting.php">` and `if (isset($_GET['submit1']))`. Do you understand the difference between GET and POST?

Answer (score 1):

I followed ADyson last comment by changing the POST request to GET and it worked perfectly well. The tables are now sortnig well. Thanks ADyson. I am very grateful. The complete code is now:

```
<?php
 $orderBy = "amount";
 $order = "asc";

 if(!empty($_GET["orderby"])) {
 $orderBy = $_GET["orderby"];}
  if(!empty($_GET["order"])) {
  $order = $_GET["order"];}

  $firstname = "asc"; $lastname = "asc"; $amount = 
"desc";

if($orderBy == "firstname" and $order == "asc") {
$firstname = "desc";}
if($orderBy == "lastname" and $order == "asc") {
$lastname = "desc";}
if($orderBy == "amount" and $order == "desc"){
$amount = "asc";}
if (isset($_GET['submit1'])) {  
  try { 
 echo "<table id='Table1' class='table table_bordered'>
<thead><tr><th><a href='?submit1=submit1&
orderby=firstname&order=$firstname'>First 
Name</a></th><th><a href='? 
submit1=submit1&orderby=lastname&order=$lastname'>Last 
Name</a></th><th><a href=? 
      submit1=submit1&orderby=amount&order=$amount'>Amount</a></th></tr></thead>"; 

$result = $pdo->query("SELECT firstname, lastname, 
amount 
from table1 where (amount != 0) ORDER BY $orderBy 
$order");
  foreach ($result as $row) {    
  echo "<tbody><tr><td>{$row['firstname']}</td><td> 
{$row['lastname']}</td><td>{$row['amount']}</td></tr> 
</tbody>";}} }  

<form method="GET" action="headerSorting.php">
   <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit1">
</form>
```